# Outbound connection in Azure VM

Tags: java, networking, ubuntu, azure

We can't connect to external resources from virtual machine (Ubuntu 13.10) in Azure. Connection break after timeout or connect a lot of time later.

Traceroute shows that there is a problem with  network. Only with TTL greater than 20 turns to connect to resource.

```
traceroute to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (54.243.69.182), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  ec2-54-243-69-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.243.69.182)  84.343 ms  81.948 ms  81.601 ms
```

Tried to change default DNS to 8.8.8.8, did not help.

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
 at com.sun.jersey.client.apache.DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.executeMethod(DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.java:213)
 at com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClientHandler.handle(ApacheHttpClientHandler.java:175)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
```

Comment: So the real question is: how do I increase the socket timeout in Azure VM?

Comment: @Gimby sorry, no. Question is: why so long and is normal for Azure?

Comment: You are blaming Azure for your network problems?

Comment: I don't know. I tried several times to clean version of Ubuntu with Tomcat only. And every time the same, not only for amazonaws.com. But in AWS VM it's work.

Comment: Wild guessing and finger pointing isn't going to get you anywhere. Likely you can't solve this yourself, if there is trouble in the network then the source of that trouble needs to be hunted down. It may be a faulty switch or a badly configured firewall - basically anything.

Comment: @Gimby, thanks you. I'll try to check settings of firewall in OS.

Answer (score 0):

**Azure blocks the ICMP protocol**, so you won't be able to use `traceroute` or `ping`. Try testing connectivity with something like:

`nc -vz -w 1 54.243.69.182 22`

or if you want to mimic the behavior of repeated pings how about:

`while true; do nc -vz -w 1 54.243.69.182 22; sleep 1; done`

Good output example:

`Connection to 54.243.69.182 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!`

Bad output example:

`nc: connect to 54.243.69.182 port 22 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress`

Make sure that the **port** you're hitting (22 in this example) is open to your Azure host's IP, in your **EC2 security group**. Please also note that **Azure assigns an external IP address** that may change if you stop and start your VM (unless you assign it a virtual IP). Here's a nifty way to find out your Internet IP address from the command line of your Azure host:

`curl http://ifconfig.me/`